# counting words excepts the whitespace from file

Tags: c

I am trying to count words from file called file.txt but it gives me charecters with whitespace.
How to count words without counting the whitespace?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{

 FILE *f1;
 char c;
 clrscr();

 printf("data output");
 f1 = fopen("file.txt","r");
 while((c=getc(f1))!=EOF)
 {
   printf("%c",c);
 }
 fclose(f1);
 getch();
}
```

Please help me to solve it as soon as possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: and how exactly you are `count`ing in above code? can you please let us know that `as soon as possible`?

Comment: Consider using `fgets()` to read a line and use `strtok()` to separate words and spaces.

Comment: i was counting words from the file but i didnt know it for words so it was giving me charecters with whitespace.

Comment: how to use strtok() ? please let me know as i have only basic knowledge of c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Create a char array to store a word
char word[100];
// Stop when fscanf returns 0
while(fscanf(f1, "%s", word)==1)
{
    // print the word
    printf("%s ",word);
    // Increment count
    count ++;
}
// Print count
printf("%d\n", count );
```

Remember it assumes that no word is longer than 100 characters since `fscanf` does't check for buffer overflow